# Sql server - The provided statistics stream is corrupt

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to create statistics on a table that already exists. I kept getting this error : The provided statistics steam is corrupt on some of the stats i am trying to create, but not all.

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?
Please help

This is one of my stats query just for information:

```
if not exists (select * from sys.stats where name = N'_WA_Sys_00000034_452AF57A' and object_id = object_id(N'[dbo].[PromotionBenefit]'))
CREATE STATISTICS [_WA_Sys_00000034_452AF57A] ON [dbo].[PromotionBenefit]([DeductPointValue]) WITH STATS_STREAM = 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
GO
```

EDIT: So basically, I am doing data archiving on some tables in my database. Only one server is in use. Let's say I have tableA and I want to archive it . The step would be :
 1. Create a new table with same columns as tableA , let's call it tableA_New. Then transfer records i want from original table to the new table. Then drop original table and rename the new table to original table name,i.e tableA.

After that, I would add back those constraints,triggers,indexes,statistics associated with table A back into it. 
That's where some stats I tried to add, it would throw me the error, only happens with some stats i am trying to create.

Comment: What is the error message you are receiving? And what version of SQL Server are you using? I'd also like to bring to your attention that supplying the STATS_STREAM option is not supported. The documentation states *STATS_STREAM: Identified for informational purposes only. Not supported. Future compatibility is not guaranteed.*

Comment: I am using SSMS 2017 . Error message: The provided statistics stream is corrupt

Comment: I imagine you want to clone the statistics from prod db to test db, so maybe you have 2 servers and their versions are different? Please update your question with the info from where you are taking this statistics

Comment: See my edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possibly due to the fact that the `STATS_STREAM` value that you are implementing is faulty. This can have multiple reasons, none of which seem to documented outside of Microsoft.

### Official Documentation

The only useful reference to `STATS_STREAM` comes from the official Microsoft Documentation *[CREATE STATISTICS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-statistics-transact-sql)* in which Microsoft states:

> `STATS_STREAM =stats_stream`
>
> Identified for informational purposes only. Not supported. Future compatibility is not guaranteed.

That says quite a lot about this parameter.

> *We (Microsoft) use it, but you (end-user) shouldn't.*

### (non-official) use case for `STATS_STREAM`

There is a case that has been blogged about by Thomas Kejser in which he uses "faked" `STATS_STREAM`s to populate a "smaller" table with values that could possibly be produced in the future.

He goes on to explain a possible situation in which you would want to implement "wrong" statistics in order to deceive the query analyzer to use "fabricated" statistics to produce a better execution plan for values that have only just been inserted and are thus not normally updated fast enough:

> There is another approach that does not rely on the optimizer making guesses: You can intentionally deceive the optimizer, lie about the distribution. Recall that we want the “desired DW plan”. Alas, as with all telling of lies, this exposes you to a lot of risk.

***Reference:*** [The Ascending Key Problem In Fact Tables –Part Two: Stat Job!](http://blog.kejser.org/the-ascending-column-problem-in-fact-tables-part-two-stat-job/)

### Situation at hand

However, your situation does not look like you want to deceive the query optimizer, but to just recreate the system generated statistics on your migrated table.

Now because you have modified a large amount of data, by deleting the records you no longer require, you are possibly invalidating the `STATS_STREAM` value that you retrieved from the original table.

#### Solutions

**Option 1**

Instead of trying to fill the system generated statistics with "fake" values that don't seem to work, why not just create new statistics for the columns that have had automatic statistics created for them?

You would just take your individual statements and instead of using the system generated name, replace it with a user defined name:

```
CREATE STATISTICS [PromotionBenefit_DeductPointValue] ON [dbo].[PromotionBenefit]([DeductPointValue])
```

This has the advantage that the statistics are created correctly and do not have to rely on fake values.

You can determine the columns of the system generated statistics by running the following statement:

```
SELECT s.name AS statistics_name
      ,c.name AS column_name  
      ,sc.stats_column_id  
FROM sys.stats AS s  
INNER JOIN sys.stats_columns AS sc   
    ON s.object_id = sc.object_id AND s.stats_id = sc.stats_id  
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c   
    ON sc.object_id = c.object_id AND c.column_id = sc.column_id  
WHERE s.object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.PromotionBenefit')
AND s.name LIKE '_WA_Sys_%'
ORDER BY 1,3
```

This will give you a list of all system generated statistics for your table and the columns in the statistics.

**Option 2**

Just insert the data and let the database engine created new system generated statistics as soon as queries are performed against the table.

Comment: What are the main purpose of stats?

Comment: Or should I leave out those stats that could not be created?

Comment: [Statistics (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/statistics/statistics) explained by Microsoft. Bluntly put, statistics are a means for the query optimizer to determine which index to use to retrieve the requested data as fastest as possible.They are an estimated map of the distribution of the data in the (clustered-) index or  column.

Comment: What about those that could not be created? Should i leave them out?

Comment: The `_WA_Sys_....` statistics are (in most cases) system generated statistics. If the query optimizer determines that a statistic on a index or on a column is required and missing, then it will automatically create the missing statistics for you (if the `AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS` option is on; see link). You can leave them out and check to see if the system creates them again after you perform a query against the table. In testing I had a `_WA_Sys_....` column statistic after one single query on a table with only 5 records and 1 clustered index.

Answer (score 0):

> I am doing data archiving on some tables in my database.
>   ...
>
> Then transfer records i want from original table to the new table.
>
> ...
>
> After that, I would add back those
>   constraints,triggers,indexes,statistics associated with table A back
>   into it. That's where some stats I tried to add, it would throw me the
>   error, only happens with some stats i am trying to create.

All this is fine except for transfering old statistics.

Statistics are used to build optimal execution plan, they reflect data distribution in your columns.

When you'll query your new table, all the missing statistics will be recreated unless you disabled `AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS` (the option is ON by default).

If you set `AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS` to `OFF` and want to recreate all the statistics that existed on the old table **you should just recreate them**, all that you need for this is to know on what columns old statistics were created.

This way you'll get fresh statistics on your new table.

The undocumented option that you was trying to use serve another purpose:
it's used with update statistics **to recreate the same statistics in another environment**. Here "the same" means not to use the same column to create statistics, but set another, not actual statistics, statistics taken from another table with another data distribution, on your table.

I mean if your original table had 1000 rows and half of them had col1 = 0 and another 500 rows had col1 = 1, you could create the same table on another server, put there only one row, and transfer data distribution as 500 rows having 0 + 5000 rows having 1. And this is not what you want. You want real data distribution on your new table, so just create the statistics on col1 that will reflect what is now in this table without using `WITH STATS_STREAM`.

Comment: Should i just recreate the ones that throw the error? What about those stats that were successfully created?

Comment: If you want to have reasonable plans that are made based on real statistics that reflect your new tables content, you should update statistics already created. As I understand, you don't copy all the rows from original tables, i.e. you have less rows that your statistics reflect, this means you'll have overestimation of these tables that can lead to inappropriate scans, wrong join types, exaggerated memory grants.

Comment: So what should I do now? Leave it as it is for those successful stats created?

Comment: I already answered you: >>> you should update statistics already created<<<. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/update-statistics-transact-sql (see example A)

Comment: I already did that but say I have 3 updated stats in the table and the rest are meant for creating stats, what could be done about those meant to be created??

Comment: Why do you want to recreate the statistics? If you recreated all the indexes, statistics for them are already created. The column statistics will be created as soon as a query will need them. Or you have disabled AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS on your db?

Comment: I don't really want to recreate statistics. Like i mentioned it's for data archiving, I meant to copy over constraint,indexes,triggers,keys, and stats over to the archived table. Only creating stats throw the error. At first I thought i could just copy over like constraints and indexes etc but it turns out statistics behave independently to different table. So that's probably an unwise idea to do so.

Comment: To put it clearly, yes when I create new table, statistics are already created but I meant to say is those "Histogram" with keyname = "WA....." which are also stored in Statistics section. They are the only one not copied forward and that's the reason I tried to brute force them to create to my new table, of course that didn't turn out pretty good at all.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. You was trying to recreate column statistics WA...and got the error. I said to not create it using STATS_STREAM. Then you have the option to manually create it without specifying STATS_STREAM, or to not create it at all. What is your problem? Was you unable to just create it on a new table? What is your new error in this case?

Comment: The problem is when I tried to create new statistics ( scripted from original table) , some of the stats (not all) with stats stream throw an error: The provided statistics stream is corrupt. That's all there is to it. I didn't write the create statistics script by myself, all I did was script statistics (in option) and copy statistics and histograms.

Comment: I assume that those that are automatically created stats are those indexes etc which are created without any issue. Only when I tried to create statistics WA ( referring to histogram), then it throws the error. It's strange because it only throws error on some statistics, but not all. So I was wondering why this happened?

Comment: Like you mentioned, those statistics histograms are created when query is run against that table, so is that why I get that error with stat stream being corrupt? It belongs to only one table and cannot be copied?

Comment: To create statistics in WELL DOCUMENTED WAY you should NOT use STATS_STREAM, but you insisted and did use it. This option is not documented and is not supported, so you cannot even say something to Microsoft: they did not guarantee anything if you use it. I cannot tell you if they were corrupred/truncated when you exported them using  STATS_STREAM or it's a problem only to apply them to new tables, but you can try to ask about it someone who blogged about this undocumented option